# Spring @PostConstruct depending on @Profile

Tags: java, spring, configuration, postconstruct

I'd like to have multiple @PostConstruct annotated methods in one configuration class, that should be called dependent on the @Profile. You can imagine a code snipped like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SilentaConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SilentaConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct @Profile("test")
    public void logImportantInfomationForTest() {
        LOG.info("********** logImportantInfomationForTest");
    }

    @PostConstruct @Profile("development")
    public void logImportantInfomationForDevelopment() {
        LOG.info("********** logImportantInfomationForDevelopment");
    }   
}
```

However according to the javadoc of @PostConstruct I can only have one method annotated with this annotation. There is an open improvement for that in Spring's Jira https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12433.

How do you solved this requirement? I can always split this configuration class into multiple classes, but maybe you have a better idea/solution.

BTW. The code above runs without problems, however both methods are called regardless of the profile settings.

Comment: Just do it yourself. The `Environment` can tell you if a profile is active or not.  So create a simple if statement.

Comment: or split your class into two, each one with the proper @Profile annotated at class level

Comment: Vote for this issue mate: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12433

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved it with one class per `@PostConstruct` method. (This is Kotlin but it translates to Java almost 1:1.)

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class Backend {

    @Configuration
    @Profile("integration-test")
    open class IntegrationTestPostConstruct {

        @PostConstruct
        fun postConstruct() {
            // do stuff in integration tests
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("test")
    open class TestPostConstruct {

        @PostConstruct
        fun postConstruct() {
            // do stuff in normal tests
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Works well, interestingly when I add an \@Profile(...) to my normal \@Configuration \@PostConstruct method it is ignored. Yet subclassing works and allows you to hit multiple PostConstruct if you really wanted (STS 4/Springboot 3.1.1 - not sure if it's supposed to according to spec, https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/annotation/postconstruct).

Answer (score 9):

You can check for profile with `Environment` within a single `@PostContruct`.

An `if` statement would do the trick.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Can you add an example?